ModuleNotFoundError in VSCode Conda Environment But Not When Opening VSCode Through Anaconda Prompt
I am relatively new to coding and more specifically Python. I was working on a course through Coursera and one of the projects that I decided to tackle on my local machine required me to install the Flask package. I created and activated a virtual environment using conda named "venv_Flask" and ran "pip install Flask" to install the package. The package installed and can be confirmed through "Flask --version" which outputs "Python 3.9.19 Flask 3.0.3 Werkzeug 3.0.3". However, when I try to run the Python script in a .py file (the file has only one line "from flask import Flask") in VSCode (where the selected interpreter is my conda environment "venv_Flask"), I get a "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named flask". The interesting thing is however, that when I open Anaconda prompt, run "conda activate venv_Flask", and then run "code" (which opens VSCode within venv_Flask), the same .py file runs without error. Any explanation/solution would be great. Thank you.
Attached are some screenshots of both instances, the right is just opening VSCode as normal, selecting the interpreter as "venv_Flask" (as seen in the bottom right), and running the script. The left is opening Anaconda Prompt running the commands shown and running the same Python script. In the second screenshot, you can also see the confirmation of Flask installation and Python version for both examples. Both have exactly the same versions installed and venv_Flask prefix before the directory indicating that I am within the activated environment. Also, I did make sure to add both Python and Conda to PATH.



Why is the result of the run displayed in the output tab.
I assume you're using the code-runner extension.
Please use the Run Python File choice which is provided by Python extension.

If you want to use code-runner, you need to set your python interpreter in the settings.json by adding $pythonPath.

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=formulahendry.code-runner
